# Difference between assign_to_config and config (and or env_config)

Tags: stash, config, focus-lab-master-config, config-overrides

I'm using [EE Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) along with Stash.

I know in Master Config that all the configs have been changed from `$config['']` to `$env_config['']`

I noticed with Stash that Mark is using this format: `$assign_to_config['']`

You can see what I mean [here](https://github.com/croxton/Stash#installation) in the dev branch of 2.3.6

I guess I'm wondering what is the different between $config and $assign_to_config

I usually just convert that over to the EE Master Config format though, now that I think of it, I've never really known what was the proper format or why the assign_to_config format exist in the first place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$assign_to_config` is an EE-native array used in the index.php file. Here's part of the comments EllisLab left for us to provide context:

> The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
>    config class. This allows you to set custom config items or override
>    any default config values found in the config.php file.  This can
>    be handy as it permits you to share one application between more then
>    one front controller file, with each file containing different 
>    config values.

The use of `$env_config` in our (Focus Lab's) config approach is to clearly display what is set in our config files vs what's set in `index.php`.

> I guess I'm wondering what is the different between $config and $assign_to_config

Really the only difference between these two is that `$config` is set in the `config.php` file and `$assign_to_config` is set in the `index.php` file.

They all achieve the same goal though.

It's probably worth noting that if an array key exists in both the `$config` array and the `$assign_to_config` array, the latter will take precedent.

Comment: So in the case of $assign_to_config in regards to Master Config should we just leave as is or convert to $env_config format or does it make no difference? Mark says this: "of course if you're using a custom config bootstrap file, add the config items there instead"

Comment: The original purpose of `$assign_to_config` was to enable multiple front-ends (or "front controller file") with these variables. You can technically change other config settings there, but I wouldn't suggest it. I say stick to `config.php` or your bootstrap of choice (`config.master.php` in this case).

Comment: I'm sticking with config.master.php of course though, should I change the format of the $assign_to_config to read as $env_config like everything else in EE Master Config or should it stay as is? (sorry, not sure I was clear at first.)

Comment: In theory either should work. For consistency I would recommend `$env_config` though. There's [a section for 3rd party settings/overrides](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config/blob/master/config/config.master.php#L201) waiting for you :)

Comment: Awesome! So they are interchangeable in a sense (at least in context of this conversation.) Great, thanks for your help Erik! Oh, I'm aware of that 3rd party settings section and do in fact use it often :)